# Algorithm for auto tiling of tiles in a 2D tile map

Tags: c++, c++17, iteration

## Introduction

I have implemented an algorithm that applies auto tiling to a 2D tile map for a game, selecting the correct tiles according to their neighborhood. Given a string representation in a classic roguelike form such as this

[image: Input]

the algorithm yields a generated map with properly connected tiles as follows

[image: Output]

## Algorithm

The general idea of the algorithm is to create a distinct bitmask that indicates in which directions neighbors of the same kind are already available.

[image: Setup]

In the sample image a tile in the center has a value based on its adjacent tiles (and corners under a particular conditition described later). Since the adjacent tiles at N, NE and E are of the same kind the tile has a total value of 2 + 4 + 16.

Corners only contribute to the value of a tile if their cardinal neighbors connecting the corners to the center are of the same kind as well. Therefore the SE and SW tiles would not be considered for calculation of the tile value no matter their kind unlike the NE tile.

The mapping of adjacencies to tiles is visualized in my use case as follows:

[image: Mapping]

## Implementation

Using this algorithm one has 48 different configurations and mappings of tile value to actual tile/sprite from the tileset. I have cleaned some parts of my code and would like to receive further input what may be improved. The core problem was to compute the atlas index to deduce the coordinates in the atlas via the `std::unordered_map`.

All unrelated data and methods have been removed from the code for review purposes:

```cpp
class TileMap : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable {
public:
  auto loadFromString(const std::string &String, const sf::Vector2<uint16> Size)
      -> bool {
    Data = String;
    Width = Size.x;
    Height = Size.y;

    // ... snip ...

    for (auto Column = 0; Column < Width; ++Column) {
      for (auto Row = 0; Row < Height; ++Row) {
        auto Tile = Data[Column + Row * Width];

        // ... snip ...

        auto Index = atlasIndexAt(Column, Row, Tile);
        auto AtlasPosition = Atlas[Index];
        
        // ... snip ...
      }
    }

    return true;
  }

private:
  auto atlasIndexAt(const uint16 Column, const uint16 Row, const char Tile)
      -> uint8 {
    auto T = tileValueAt(Column, Row - 1, Tile);
    auto L = tileValueAt(Column - 1, Row, Tile);
    auto R = tileValueAt(Column + 1, Row, Tile);
    auto B = tileValueAt(Column, Row + 1, Tile);
    // Corners are only relevant if both cardinals connecting the corner to the
    // center tile have positive value.
    auto TL = (T == 0 || L == 0) ? 0 : tileValueAt(Column - 1, Row - 1, Tile);
    auto TR = (T == 0 || R == 0) ? 0 : tileValueAt(Column + 1, Row - 1, Tile);
    auto BL = (B == 0 || L == 0) ? 0 : tileValueAt(Column - 1, Row + 1, Tile);
    auto BR = (B == 0 || R == 0) ? 0 : tileValueAt(Column + 1, Row + 1, Tile);
    return TL * 1 + T * 2 + TR * 4 + L * 8 + R * 16 + BL * 32 + B * 64 +
           BR * 128;
  }

  auto tileValueAt(const uint16 Column, const uint16 Row, const char Tile)
      -> uint8 {
    if (Column >= Width || Row >= Height ||
        Column == std::numeric_limits<uint16>::max() ||
        Row == std::numeric_limits<uint16>::max()) {
      return 1;
    }
    return Data[Column + Row * Width] == Tile ? 1 : 0;
  }

  // ... snip ...

  uint16 Width;
  uint16 Height;
  std::string Data;
  std::unordered_map<uint8, sf::Vector2<uint8>> Atlas{
      {208, sf::Vector2<uint8>(0, 0)},
      {248, sf::Vector2<uint8>(1, 0)},
      {104, sf::Vector2<uint8>(2, 0)},
      // ... snip ...
  };
};
```

Comment: You could also just create a giant jump table with all possible combinations for your algorithm.